# Changing font size in custom document class

Tags: macros, fontsize, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I am writing my own document class and would like to include a macro that makes the main text in my document 12pt. Everyone online says to do this with `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` however I can't use this since I am not using the generic article class.
Is there a macro that can do this without using the article document class?

Comment: just look at what article does for 12pt and do the same

Comment: Which is `\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo er well yes but that  pre-supposes the class has defined it (and made it do something)

Comment: Just as a note: For beginners in writing classes, it is usually easier if they do not build a class from scratch, but write a so-called wrapper class that loads one of the standard classes as a base. At least class authors should read the documentation of the standard classes. [`classes.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf) is usually part of the documentation tree of TeX distributions. You should also read [`clsguide.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/clsguide.pdf) and several more basic documentation.

Comment: Note: If you are using lualatex (possibly xetex, not sure), you can also use decimal values for the font size (such as 11.6pt). This is tricky, involves loading certain packages in a certain order, does not play well with standard document classes, and may require you to define `\normalsize` twice. But I have done it.

Comment: @rallg that is also possible with pdfTeX, as long as you're using a scalable font.